# Create unit tests for class library (no metro) vs11

Tags: unit-testing, class-library, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to make a standard class library in vs11 with more available classes than a library with metro offers (for example System.Console) and I cannot figure out how to create unit tests for it. I have tried looking through Google an nothing works. I actually had to go into vs2010, create the project, add the tests, and reopen in vs11. Was this functionality removed (which I doubt. I know unit testing is available)?

I have seen the unit test library project type, but it does not seem to support this type of library. What are my options?

Comment: Adam, which edition of VS11 are you using?

Comment: Sorry about taking so long. I thought this post had died. I will try these answers when I can.  I think I am running vs11 ultimate. But I will check. Also I don't remember seeing a tests catagory, but again, I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you asking but If I understood you correctly, you want to create a standard class library and a standard Unit test project for the class library? Did you check the project templates under "Test". In here you can create a Unit Test project for the class library. You do not have to go to VS2010 and create a Test project then open it in VS. Apologies if that's not what you asking for.

Comment: no that's right. This turned out to be a stupid me moment. Under the tests catagory the one item worked. I was using a unit test LIBRARY not unit test PROJECT.

Answer (score 0):

As Raj said, just create a standard class library, reference the test framework you want to write tests in and then add test code as per usual.

For MSTest you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` and for the others use NuGet.

I have a blog post showing [how the new unit test explorer works](http://www.richard-banks.org/2012/03/get-visual-studio-11-beta-right-now-for.html) that might be helpful